# How do I create a dataframe out of a long string which was supposed to be a dictionary?

Tags: python

I received an excel file containing some JSON data which looks like this:-

> {\currentPortfolioId":null/"isNewRTQ":true/"isNewInvestmentTenure":true/"isNearTermVolatility":false/"getPath":true/"riskProfile":"Moderate"/"initialInvestment":200000/"cashflowDate":"01-01-2021"/"currentWealth":200000/"goalPriority":"Wish"/"rebalancing":"yearly"/"goalAmount":2000000/"startDate":"16-06-2021"/"endDate":"01-01-2031"/"isNewGoalPriority":true/"infusions":[0/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/0]/"scenario_type":"regular"/"infusion_type":"monthly"/"xforwardForValue":"49.228.234.102:49907/ 13.86.190.104:3072/ 172.30.217.148:36243"}"

A point to note here is that the above data is just one cell of the excel file, there is similar data located in many other cells of the excel file, the key pairs are similar in all the data as the one mentioned above.

As I extracted the data into python I converted it into a dictionary, as the data is mangled with lots of "/" and "" I cleaned the data by removing these symbols and replacing "/" with "," to make it like a dictionary.

After cleaning I found out that the dictionary is mangled, as "" were missing in some places where it should be:-

> 1L: '{currentPortfolioId:null,isNewRTQ:true,isNewInvestmentTenure:true,isNearTermVolatility:false,getPath:true,riskProfile:Moderate,initialInvestment:200000,cashflowDate:01-01-2021,currentWealth:200000,goalPriority:Wish,rebalancing:yearly,goalAmount:2000000,startDate:16-06-2021,endDate:01-01-2031,isNewGoalPriority:true,infusions:0,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,0,scenario_type:regular,infusion_type:monthly,xforwardForValue:49.228.234.102:49907, 13.86.190.104:3072, 172.30.217.148:36243}'

As it is visible the data appears like a long long string after cleaning rather than a proper dict. How can I use this dict to make a dataframe which can contain the columns like given in the data:- riskprofile, inititalinvestment, riskprofile, cashflowdate, infusions etc. so that the subsequent values of those key pairs inside that long string falls into subsequent rows, just like a dataframe.

Comment: The best solution in cases like this is to see if you can get the process that generated the data to produce clean JSON instead of the mangled version they put in there. If that's not possible, then you're usually stuck writing some sort of custom parsing function.

Comment: I just got the Excel file directly, can't get hands on the API which generated this data

Comment: Then you're stuck with option 2.

Comment: I am a beginner in python, if you can help me with that or give me some clue it would be of great help

Comment: You just need to keep doing what you were doing where you were converting characters to try to make it into a valid JSON dictionary. Alternatively, if you only need a few elements from it, you can pick those out a bit more directly with regular expressions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I took the raw data the one you mentioned above and did some changes and considering the string to be

`'{"\currentPortfolioId":null/"isNewRTQ":true/"isNewInvestmentTenure":true/"isNearTermVolatility":false/"getPath":true/"riskProfile":"Moderate"/"initialInvestment":200000/"cashflowDate":"01-01-2021"/"currentWealth":200000/"goalPriority":"Wish"/"rebalancing":"yearly"/"goalAmount":2000000/"startDate":"16-06-2021"/"endDate":"01-01-2031"/"isNewGoalPriority":true/"infusions":[0/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/10000/0]/"scenario_type":"regular"/"infusion_type":"monthly"/"xforwardForValue":"49.228.234.102:49907/ 13.86.190.104:3072/ 172.30.217.148:36243"}'`

Then the next thing to be done was to replace "/" with "," and "\" to "" using str.replace() in python. The output I got was -

`'{"currentPortfolioId":null,"isNewRTQ":true,"isNewInvestmentTenure":true,"isNearTermVolatility":false,"getPath":true,"riskProfile":"Moderate","initialInvestment":200000,"cashflowDate":"01-01-2021","currentWealth":200000,"goalPriority":"Wish","rebalancing":"yearly","goalAmount":2000000,"startDate":"16-06-2021","endDate":"01-01-2031","isNewGoalPriority":true,"infusions":[0,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,0],"scenario_type":"regular","infusion_type":"monthly","xforwardForValue":"49.228.234.102:49907, 13.86.190.104:3072, 172.30.217.148:36243"}'`

Then I simply used json.loads() function and the data was converted into the dictionary. The output would be something like this -

`{'currentPortfolioId': None, 'isNewRTQ': True, 'isNewInvestmentTenure': True, 'isNearTermVolatility': False, 'getPath': True, 'riskProfile': 'Moderate', 'initialInvestment': 200000, 'cashflowDate': '01-01-2021', 'currentWealth': 200000, 'goalPriority': 'Wish', 'rebalancing': 'yearly', 'goalAmount': 2000000, 'startDate': '16-06-2021', 'endDate': '01-01-2031', 'isNewGoalPriority': True, 'infusions': [0, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 0], 'scenario_type': 'regular', 'infusion_type': 'monthly', 'xforwardForValue': '49.228.234.102:49907, 13.86.190.104:3072, 172.30.217.148:36243'} ​`

Comment: Yes this definitely helps but I have 50 rows of the same kind of data, doing the initial change you did on the data will take a very long time, any other way to do it quickly?

Comment: @ParvSuhane does the data not contain " in the starting of the string. If it is present the simply we can replace the starting and ending double quotaions (") to single quotations (') and rest is the same

Comment: That is the problem, the data does not have "" at the start